# When to use requestAnimationFrame? and why we need requestAnimationFrame if we have css transition?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-transitions

I don't know When to use requestAnimationFrame.
If requestAnimationFrame and css both can satisfy my needs, which one should I choose?

can you show me some of your Applied Cases?

thx very much~

Comment: Their purpose is not the same. rAF is a timing function for javascript code execution. CSS animations are only for elements display. If you need to animate an element from x1 to x2 use CSS, if you need to perform some javascript (such as drawing on a canvas), use rAF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only reason to opt for `requestAnimationFrame` over CSS animations is when you want to do quick animations where you need to ensure that browsers would make it smooth. Animations like jump, stop, pause, return could benefit from using `requestAnimationFrame`.

The thing is that `requestAnimationFrame` uses no CPU power, and only draws animation that would be visible to the user (it doesn't consume anything if you swich tabs, minimize, etc). Frames would be only drawn when the browser is ready and since there are no ready frames waiting to be drawn, there are no unnecessary frame draws. So, for *smoothness* guarantee, you can safely opt for `requestAnimationFrame`.

If you plan something simple that doesn't fit the above explanation, then `requestAnimationFrame` is overkill and you'd better switch to CSS animations.

**Source consulted:**

https://dev.opera.com/articles/better-performance-with-requestanimationframe/